# for en matriz javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, chart.js

Es una pregunta muy sencilla, pero no consigo darle solución... Necesito recorrer un array en javascript, pero siempre que intento recorrer dicho array se me queda en el indice 0...

```
<script>
            let status = [];
            let number = [];
            let llamadas = [];
            
            llamadas = {!! json_encode($estados) !!}
            
            for(var i=0; i<llamadas.length; i++){
                console.log(llamadas[i][i]);

                status.push(llamadas[i][i].desc);
                number.push(llamadas[i][i].total)
            }
```

`Llamadas` contiene el contenido de una variable de php que viene del controlador (estados), como backend estoy trabajando con laravel 5.6.

El contenido del array llamadas es:

```
(7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id_teleoperadora: 9, desc: "APLAZADA", total: 40}
1: {id_teleoperadora: 9, desc: "AUSENTE", total: 132}
2: {id_teleoperadora: 9, desc: "CONFIRMADA", total: 218}
3: {id_teleoperadora: 9, desc: "NUEVA", total: 101}
4: {id_teleoperadora: 9, desc: "NULA", total: 217}
5: {id_teleoperadora: 9, desc: "PENDIENTE", total: 45}
6: {id_teleoperadora: 9, desc: "VENTA", total: 1}
length: 7
__proto__: Array(0)
```

y su contenido original sin mostrarlo en el for es:

```
[Array(7)]
0: (7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

nunca me he encontrado arrays así

y en el `push de status` necesito ir sacando `desc` para crear un chartJS de estadisticas. Actualmente solo me esta sacando `aplazada`... No se que estoy haciendo mal. Una vez tenga los estados, haré lo mismo para total. Pero no se como ir introduciendo los datos en dichos array.

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: No esta claro de donde sacas el primer resultado y de donde el segundo. Si `llamadas` en Javascript es igual al primero, debería funcionar. Si es igual a segundo, si te fijas con cuidado, `llamadas` es un arreglo que contiene un arreglo (_donde estan los datos_); traducido... `llamadas[0]` debería ser igual al primer resultado.

Comment: @Marcos exactamente, era accediendo a [0][i] ya he conseguido arreglarlo. Gracias

Comment: Intenta hacer directamente asi, llamadas = {!! json_encode($estados) !!}[0] para saltear ese inconveniente.